# How to output colored text to stdout while also appending the text uncolored to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, colors

I wrote a logger function that is supposed to output colored text to screen while also redirecting the text to a log file using the `tee` command.

This the logger function:

```
function logger(){
    GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
    YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
    BOLD=$(tput bold)
    UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)
    NOCOLOR=$(tput sgr0)

    case "$1" in
        y)
        echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${YELLOW}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee -a $log_file
        ;;
        g)
        echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${GREEN}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee -a $log_file
        ;;
        b)
        echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${BOLD}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee -a $log_file
        ;;
        u)
        echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${UNDERLINE}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee -a $log_file
        ;;
        n)
        echo -e -n "$(timestamp) $2\n" | tee -a $log_file
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Unknown color!"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

The problem is that when the text is written in the log file, the color codes are also applied and it makes the text seem dirty.

This is how it looks:

```
2021-08-31 12:36:41 UTC +0000 ^[[1m------------ Now working on account CompanyEUResearchAndDevelopmentJenkinsSlave in region us-east-2 ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:42 UTC +0000 ^[[32mThe following IPs are allocated and associated: ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:42 UTC +0000 13.11.131.202 18.11.34.219 3.11.227.231
2021-08-31 12:36:42 UTC +0000 ----------------------------------------------------------
2021-08-31 12:36:44 UTC +0000 ^[[33mFound unassociated elastic ips: ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:44 UTC +0000 18.11.91.21
2021-08-31 12:36:45 UTC +0000 ^[[33mIP 18.11.91.21 found in groups: ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:45 UTC +0000 sg-04b6da1d06783ffbf
2021-08-31 12:36:46 UTC +0000 ^[[32mThe rule containing ip 18.11.91.21 has been deleted from security group sg-04b6da1d06783ffbf successfully ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:46 UTC +0000 ^[[32mReleasing ip 18.11.91.21 with AllocationId eipalloc-07528d88e8794c6db ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:46 UTC +0000 ^[[32mAllocation released successfully! ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:47 UTC +0000 ^[[33mFound unassociated elastic ips: ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:47 UTC +0000 3.11.248.103
2021-08-31 12:36:48 UTC +0000 ^[[33mIP 3.11.248.103 found in groups: ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:48 UTC +0000 sg-04b6da1d06783ffbf
2021-08-31 12:36:49 UTC +0000 ^[[32mThe rule containing ip 3.11.248.103 has been deleted from security group sg-04b6da1d06783ffbf successfully ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:49 UTC +0000 ^[[32mReleasing ip 3.11.248.103 with AllocationId eipalloc-0a699e32f4ac844dc ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:49 UTC +0000 ^[[32mAllocation released successfully! ^[(B^[[m
2021-08-31 12:36:49 UTC +0000 End of run
```

This is how use the function:

```
logger g "No elastic ips found in account ${role_name}"
```

I wonder what's the "most right" way to do that?

Comment: Do it the other way round: Instead of piping to `tee`, append it first to the log file. Then print the colour-annotated line to stdout. You may want to consider a test, that stdout is indeed attached to a terminal.

Comment: Can you show an example please?

Comment: For what exactly? Appending to a log file, or printing to stdout?

Comment: Joining both actions to one command

Comment: Why one command? Do it in two commands. You don't earn any medal by squeezing everything into a single command.

Comment: fwiw ... if you're calling this function a lot of times you may want to consider pre-loading the `tput` codes into (exported) variables to eliminate the overhead of spawning 5 subprocesses (for the `tput` calls) **every time** you call the function ... that's a **LOT** of processing overhead (ie, *time*) for populating variables that (likely) are not changing in your environment; better yet, consider loading them into an associative array (array index == single letter codes `y/g/b/u`) and conslidate 4x of the `case/echo` combos into a single `case/echo` combo

Comment: @markp-fuso, any chance for an example?

Comment: ideas for pre-loading ... store in a resource file you call at the begnning of a shell script or (better) have the function test for the existence of the variables and if not found then call another function to load them; how/when are you loading the `logger()` function ... if sourcing a file that contains the `logger()` definition ... you could define your variables in the same file ... or a `load_colors()` function in the same file; give that a shot and if you have problems getting it to work then consider creating a new question (as opposed to going off on a tangent of this question)

Comment: @ItaiGanot updated my question to include one idea for a function that loads the colors just once thus eliminating the 5x subprocess/`tput` calls for each `logger()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modification of [Vaphell's answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2231058.html) (towards bottom of page) that removes the color codes from the `tee` stream before appending/writing to `$log_file`:

Change this:

```
echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${GREEN}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee -a $log_file
```

To this:

```
echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${GREEN}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee >(sed 's/\x1B[\[\(][0-9;]*[BJKmsu]//g' >> $log_file)
```

---

Since you're likely looking to call `logger()` quite often, performance is going to be a big issue, and the biggest improvements are going to come from eliminating as many (unnecessary) subprocess calls as possible.

**tl;dr**

- use 2x separate `echo` calls, one to stdout, one to `$log_file`
- eliminate the subprocess `$(timestamp)` call which I'm assuming includes a further subprocess call to `date`
- load the color variables (ie, `tput` subprocess calls) just once, ie, eliminate the repeated 5x subprocess calls (to `tput`) on each call to `logger()`
- for more details continue reading ...

**use 2x separate `echo` calls**

per user1934428's comment ... calling `echo` two times, once to stdout, once to (append to) `$log_file` is another option, eg:

Instead of this:

```
echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${GREEN}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | tee >(sed 's/\x1B[\[\(][0-9;]*[BJKmsu]//g' >> $log_file)
```

Use this:

```
echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${GREEN}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n"
echo -e -n "$2\n" >> $log_file
```

Using the following test:

```
time for i in {1..100}
do
    mylogger g hello > /dev/null
done
```

**NOTES:**

- on my system there is a `/usr/bin/logger` so I've named my function `mylogger()`
- I've modified my env to only load the color variables once, instead of OP's current method of making 5x `tput` calls each time the function is called (otherwise the timings for the following tests would be even worse)

Results:

```
real    0m8.739s       # echo ... | tee >(sed ... >> $log_file)
user    0m3.448s
sys     0m4.706s

real    0m0.105s       # echo ... ; echo ...
user    0m0.047s
sys     0m0.047s
```

As you can see, the use of two separate `echo` commands is going to be a **LOT** faster than the `| tee >(sed ...)` solution ... or any other solution that requires making (unnecessary) subprocess calls

**eliminate the subprocess `$(timestamp)` (and `date`) call**

I'm assuming the `$(timestamp)` call is a custom function/binary that generates a date/time string from the current `date`; if running `bash 4.2` (or better) consider using `printf` to generate the date/time string and store in a local variable, eg:

```
printf -v NOW '%(%F %H:%M:%S %Z %z)T' -1
```

**NOTES:**

- this does not require a subprocess call to `date` and therefore is going to run quite a bit faster
- see [this SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428223) for more details
- the general idea would be to make the `printf` call directly in the `logger()` function thus eliminating the `$(timestamp)` subprocess call

**load the color variables (ie, `tput` subprocess calls) just once**

As I mentioned in one of my comments, consider populating the color variables once thus eliminating the current process of making 5x subprocess calls to `tput` each time the `logger()` function is called; a very simple solution that continues to use OP's current `<color>=$(tput ...)` format:

```
function load_colors() {

    if [[ -z "${NOCOLOR}" ]]
    then
        export GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
        export YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
        export BOLD=$(tput bold)
        export UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)
        export NOCOLOR=$(tput sgr0)
    
    fi
}

function logger() {

    load_colors

    case "$1" in
    ... snip ...
    esac
}
```

Comment: Is this "(" there inentionally?

Comment: not sure which `(` you're referring to; after some testing I noticed only part of the `NOCOLOR` (`^[(B^[[m`) code was being removed (`^[(B` was not being removed); I've updated the `sed` call to remove the `^[(B)`

Answer (score 0):

Try piping before `tee` by the command `ansi2txt`.

For example:

```
echo -e -n "$(timestamp) ${UNDERLINE}$2 ${NOCOLOR}\n" | ansi2txt | tee -a $log_file
```

Comment: I try to avoid installing new tools, thanks.